# Recommend plugins for member's only e-commerce website

Tags: e-commerce, membership

I welcome recommendation from the gurus for my ecommerce website -

I want to make a ecommerce website and I want it to be for members only. I want to restrict members from visiting the dashboard.

I want guest-visitors to land on a login page , and once they login to my website they would be able to provide billing address, contact information, they would be able to shop, track orders status.

Can anyone suggest me what plugins and theme (free and premium both) would be best for my website ?

I would sell T-shirts and Canvas shoes .

The extra (must) features I want for my ecommerce website:

1. members only website (only login page visible to non-logged in visitors)
2. members will have a profile page where they can update the billing and shipping information, which will be used in future for all shopping transactions they make, with a confirmation during finalising the order.
3. HTML Email and Newsletters

P.S. - I have tested [eshop (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/eshop/). I liked it. But the only two problems with this plguin is that

1. the orders can only be tracked from the dashboard, and I have asked the developer about the code to make order tracking system a frontend page, but the developer said thats not possible.
2. No members profile page to update and save billing and shipping address (Shoppers have to fill in the personal infomations every time they order something which is annoying).

Isn't there any solution at all?

Comment: Related: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/22191/178

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Amember http://www.amember.com/p/. This is what WooThemes and a few other shops use.  I've used it myself and it's a quality product.

Answer (score 0):

I've accomplished something similar on [busAlert.me](http://busalert.me) by combining a few plugins. I started off by using the [WordPress Access Control](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-access-control/) plugin to limit the access to "members only" Then to style the plugin I used the [Theme My Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/) Plugin. Lastly I added the [WP Block Admin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-block-admin/) plugin to block dashboard access.  I modified the WP Block Admin code to redirect based on if the user is logged in like so

```
 //user is logged in take them to their profile
 if (is_user_logged_in() ) {
      $wpba_redirect_to = 'http://example.com/login/?action=profile';
 }
 //user is not logged in but is trying to view their profile make them login
else if ((stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/login/?action=profile')!== false) && (!is_user_logged_in())) {
        $wpba_redirect_to='http://example.com/login/?action=login';
        wp_redirect($wpba_redirect_to,302);
 }
//just make them login 
else{
    $wpba_redirect_to='http://example.com/login/';
}
```

It's sorta a round about way of doing it but seems to work pretty well. I also added some custom profile fields but updating the custom user meta data.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but adding this in for future readers :) [WooCommerce](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/) (by WooThemes) is easily the most solid WordPress e-commerce solution I've ever used and it does all the things you want to do here.

*Disclaimer: I work at WooThemes, but was using WooCommerce before I started working there.*